# Is it possible to unit test or assert the result of a CMD/Batch file?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, cmd, dos

I've written a block of code that's supposed to unzip compressed .cmd files and run them.

I'd like to unit test it. So far for the test I've created a very simple cmd file ("echo hello world") saved it and zipped it and processed it with my code. I can verify it works because if I replace "echo hello world" with "pause" a command window appears with the pause command. But that's obviously not automated.

Is there any way I can automate this test so that it asserts something? Running a different DOS command for example?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the batch file to `echo Whatever > %temp%\MyResult.txt`, then check that the file exists and has the correct contents.
(And delete the file both before and after)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you could just execute your existing "echo hello world" batch file and check the process' exit code.

Per convention an exit code of 0 means that the command (or batch file in your case) executed successfully.

If your batch file is valid (i.e. correctly unzipped), exists (i.e. correctly unzipped to expected location), does not force an exit code not equal to 0 (e.g. via `exit /b 1` or via invalid syntax, etc.), the exit code will always be 0.

In pseudo code your test could look like this:

```
void Test()
{
    int rc = UnzipAndExecuteBatch();

    Assert.AreEqual(0, rc);
}
```

Where UnzipAndExecuteBatch() would be your actual code, that you want to test. Probably modified, so it returns the exit code of cmd.exe.